# External program started from Perl stays hidden and is not accesibile

Tags: windows, apache, perl

I've just installed [Adobe Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server) (does contain Apache to) and Perl from [ActiveState](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState) and I struggle to find a solution to start a local application (server side) through my webpage using a Perl script.

The problem is that program is starting incorrectly and is not visible or accessible in any way. I just see it in task manager. I also tried to start other Windows programs like notepad.exe, calc.exe, mspaint.exe, etc.

The weird part is that when I run from the command line, the same script is working perfectly. All programs starts and windows are visible.

My system has Windows 7 installed and Adobe Media server with Apache 2.2.

The script is very simple:

```
#! "C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe"

system('C:\A_TV\TV.exe');
```

Comment: Take look at: http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm

Answer (score 0):

Try `system(start.exe 'C:\A_TV\TV.exe');`